# Gatling Simulating Auto Complete

Tags: scala, gatling

I am trying to create a basic performance test of some AJAX auto complete functionality.

What is the best way of doing this in Gatling?

I have a csv file containing (many) search terms, I'm using Gatling v2.1.7, I've written the following. However, I am now stuck, unable to access the actual term as a string from the feeder to generate the ChainBuilder, is it recommended/possible to get it from the session at this point or is there an easier way?

```scala
def autoCompleteChain(existingChain: ChainBuilder, searchTerm: String): ChainBuilder = {
    existingChain
        .exec(http("autocomplete")
            .get("http://localhost/autocomp?q=" + searchTerm)
            .check(substring(searchTerm)))
    .pause(1)
}

def autoCompleteTerm(term: String): ChainBuilder = {
    // build a chain of auto complete searches
    term.inits.toList.reverse.drop(1)
        .foldLeft(exec())(autoCompleteChain(_, _))
}

feed(feeder)
    // goto page
    .exec(http("home page").get("http://localhost"))
    // type query
    .exec(autoCompleteTerm("${term}"))
    // search for term etc.
    .exec(http("search").get("http://localhost/q=${term}"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed how Gatling scenarios are built: actions are chained together once and for all at load time, and the workflow is then static.

The way you're trying to build this is wrong: you try to build the request sequence depending on some information that's only available at runtime, ie later.

You have to use one of Gatlin loops, such as asLongAs, and compute the different substrings at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stephane for the clarification, I've now implemented the following:

```scala
feed(feeder)
    // goto page
    .exec(http("home page").get("http://localhost"))
    // type query
    .exec(
      foreach(session => session("term").as[String].toList, "char") {
        exec(session => session.set(
            "currentTerm",
            session("currentTerm").asOption[String].getOrElse("") + session("char").as[String]))
        .exec(http("auto-complete")
          .get("http://localhost/autocomp?q=${currentTerm}")
          .check(substring("${currentTerm}"))
        )
      }
    )
    // search for the full term
    .exec(http("search").get("http://localhost/q=${term}"))
```

Please comment if there is anything I could do to improve this code, especially from a performance or readability/style angle.